# Mysqli->error is returning a blank value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I am trying to give the error back to ajax post. But `mysqli->error` is returnin **blank**. I've tried many ways to do it, but is always the same. I don't know if there is some configuration to do on `php.ini`. Please help with that!

**HERE IS MY NOOB CODE**

```
        $sql = "UPDATE ve_industria SET industria_nome='blabla',industria_descricao='blabla' WHERE industria_Id='124142354'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
            $arr['resposta'] = "0";
            $arr['mensagem'] = $mysqli->error;
            $arr['titulo'] = "ERRO !";
            $arr['tipo'] = "error";
        }
        if ($result) {
            $arr['resposta'] = "1";
            $arr['mensagem'] = "Registro atualizado com sucesso no banco de dados :)";
            $arr['titulo']   = "Registro Atualizado !";
            $arr['tipo']     = "success";
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
```

This information, I will give back to main html with ajax page, to present in a modal box with the error specified.

Comment: Just because `$result` is "not", does NOT mean there was an error.  In fact it could just mean that the update did not *change anything*, which was not an error - but rather a "nothing was updated" result.

Comment: @cale_b Looking at the docs, mysqli::query() returns either true, false or a result object when doing SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN. What you're talking about sounds like the number of affected rows returned (which would be mysqli::$affected_rows)

Answer (score 0):

mysqli->affected_rows will give you the number of records updated with last mysql operation.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

updated your code with affected rows.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE ve_industria SET industria_nome='blabla',industria_descricao='blabla' WHERE industria_Id='124142354'";
        $mysqli->query($sql);
        if ($mysqli->affected_rows<=0) {
            $arr['resposta'] = "0";
            $arr['mensagem'] = "0 Records Updated"
            $arr['titulo'] = "ERRO !";
            $arr['tipo'] = "error";
        } else  {
            $arr['resposta'] = "1";
            $arr['mensagem'] = "Registro atualizado com sucesso no banco de dados :)";
            $arr['titulo']   = "Registro Atualizado !";
            $arr['tipo']     = "success";
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this solution will not bring the "mysqli>error ". I need to take the error to main page by json value. But mysqli->error is given a blank value.

Comment: add exception handling try, catch to $mysqli->query($sql), when there is any error occurs while executing $sql, that will go to catch, there add you response array with mysql->error.